# ORA-12154 error on server 2008

Tags: oracle, 64-bit, windows-server-2008, vb.net-2010

I'm moving a VB.NET 2010 app from a 32bit 2003 server to a 64bit 2008 server that connects to an Oracle 11g database, and am getting the following error message when executing it.

```
DefaultSource   Error   2
ERROR [08004] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
ERROR [IM006] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed
```

Here's some things I've done.

- Added the TNS_ADMIN environment variable to the server.
- Had server management install the 64bit "Oracle driver Oracle in OraClient11g_home1".  They also uninstalled the 32bit "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" driver.
- Verified I can connect to the server using SQLPlus
- Updated my connection string as I use to use the 32bit "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle"
- Added the database to the ODBC System DNS, and verified the connection worked.

Here's my connection string from my config file under the  node.

```
<add name="SCHEMA_NAME" 
 connectionString="Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};Dbq=DATABASE_NAME;uid=USER;pwd=PASSWORD;"/>
```

Any suggestions to what I can try, or what needs to be changed to get this working on the new server?

Comment: I want to add that TNSPING is working as well.

Comment: Is your app compiled as "AnyCPU" or "x86"?  Is it an IIS app?

Comment: It complies as AnyCPU, and it is executed by a batch script.  WebSphere is running on the server, but it isn't connected to the app.

Comment: I believe this part of the issue has been resolved.  My server admin disabled the 32bit ODBC connector, but didn't uninstall it.  Doing that remove the error, but added a new error message saying there's an "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow."  The error confused me as the app only does string manuplation, and traced the error to running System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader().

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by changing the way I connect to oracle.  I'm using the Oracle.DataAccess reference, removing the driver reference in the connection string, and rebuilding the connection using OracleConnection and oracleCommand.